# UITableView cell not display correct detail

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I created tableview and searchbar.

Name for cell 1 is iPhone.

When I click on the cell iPhone, on detail view it writes iPhone. When I search iPod it became the first cell in the search list but when I click this ,it writes iPhone instead of iPod. I try insert all code to here.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutootateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
      }

     #pragma  mark - Table View Methods


    - (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{


    return 1;
  }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {
  return [displayItems count];
       }


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;

 }

 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

if ([searchText length] == 0) {
    [displayItems removeAllObjects];
    [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:allItems];

} else {

    [displayItems removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString * string in allItems ){
        NSRange r =[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (r.location != NSNotFound){
            [displayItems addObject:string];
        }
    }

    [tableView reloadData];

   } 

  }





   -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)asearchBar {

   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];



      }


    - (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }


       - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath



      {
   DetailViewController *DVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

   //Pass the row to the DVC


DVC.characterNumber = [indexPath row];

//Push the DetailViewController object onto the stack

[self.navigationController pushViewController:DVC animated:YES];



 }
 @end
```

Comment: We need a little more detail.  Post the code you are using in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and if you are using Storyboards, we will also need the prepareForSegue method that you have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing to detail controller row number for allItems array, but it is not same that in displayItems

```
DVC.characterNumber = [indexPath row];
```

There is you should assing correct row from allItems array, not displayItems array

**Update:**

```
NSString *item = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row;
DVC.characterNumber = [allItems indexOfObject:item];
```